# A Trivial Pursuit #22 (Art and Literature 4/4): Bookstore

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, literature

<sub>This is part 22 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

Yesterday, I was asked to create some window displays for the bookstore where I work... well, *worked*...

Tasked with showcasing novels by the hottest authors of the moment, I took the time to read through their back-catalogues, and... well, let's just say I was very disappointed. As an act of protest before handing in my resignation, I set up a display for each author, showcasing nine of their books, particularly arranged in three rows of three, with the centremost book a little more prominent than the rest. I knew not many people would appreciate what I had done and why, but it made me feel a little better all the same...

**What was going on? The answer is an 8-letter word...**

[image: Eight 3x3 grids of book titles, one grid per author]

*<sup>Text transcription (for accessibility):</sup>*
<sup>SARA I. HITCHGATE: *Top:* A Choice of Two Dashes? / The Quartet of Enormous Proportions    / Idiocy of a Deceased Male; *Middle:* Tired of Lemmings / A Quintet of Miniature Gluttons  / The Cipher of Smokestacks; *Bottom:* A Trio of Sensible Snowshoes / The Beast of Unspeakable Tidiness / The Riddle of the Cerulean Drill.</sup>
<sup>WILMA LEAKIER-PHASES: *Top:* A Situation Made Amusing by Bungling and Incompetence / A List of Items to be Purchased on a Visit to the Supermarket / A Parcel of Minced Meat Cooked in a Tomato-Based Sauce; *Middle:* A Roman General, Statesman and Member of the First Triumvirate / A Festival to Mark the Coming of Epiphany / A Hollow Wooden Equine Statue Used as a Military Ploy; *Bottom:* A Lot of Fuss Over Something Which is Not Important / A Board Game with Sixty-Four Identical Black-and-White Pieces / A Settlement Smaller Than a Village and Lacking a Church.</sup>
<sup>INDRA CHECKLESS: *Top:* Silly Sausages / Remembering Rome / A Parable about a Pair of Places; *Middle:* Time to Talk / Where's Wilfred? / Desolate Dwelling; *Bottom:* A Companion in Common / High Hopes / Onerous Occasions.</sup>
<sup>NOEL J. ARCHER: *Top:* The Principled Student / The Bedtime Administrator / An Impeccable Agent; *Middle:* A Redundant Butcher / A Jealous Firefighter / The Perpetual Landscaper; *Bottom:* The Romantic Lumberjack / The Moribund Policewoman / A Very-Much-Desired Person.</sup>
<sup>E. W. CLISS: *Top:* The Nag And Son / The 2nd Pew / "The Cat, Hag, And Rig"; *Middle:* The End War / The Big Fat Hen / Mum And Dad Are Bad; *Bottom:* Nob Sea / Two For Tea And Jam / The Gun For The Old Man.</sup>
<sup>SEP KNIGHTEN: *Top:* Spaghetti / Cumulonimbus / Pyromaniac; *Middle:* Tetrahedron / Gravel / Tag; *Bottom:* Compartment / Sleeplessness / Despair.</sup>
<sup>TREY T. RETCH-TRAP: *Top:* Cantona/Dier / Counts & Duchesses / Custodians! Defenders!; *Middle:* Choke/Douse / Creating Dollars / Cats & Dogs; *Bottom:* Compact Deities / Corduroy/Denim / Cheese Dreams.</sup>
<sup>YEN BLONDIT: *Top:* …Haven't Got a Colin Dexter / …Go Down to John Banville / …Have a Dan Brown in Time; *Middle:* …On a Robert Louis Stevenson / …Are Milly Johnson / …Get the J.K. Rowling Back; *Bottom:* …Lose the Danielle Steel / …Harlan Coben Together / …Forget to Tell Rudyard Kipling.</sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the eight-letter-word answer is

> *plagiary*

but I only actually found the first seven of those letters. I inferred the word from the context: it's the only eight-letter word that starts with those seven, and what it means is relevant to the puzzle.

For the first seven letters,

> find an anagram of the name beneath each of the first seven grids, which is an author's name, and find which grid entries above it are sort-of synonyms of one of that author's titles. These form a pigpen-ciphered letter in the grid; the letters spell *plagiar*.

> [image]

Specifically:

> [image]

Going through each grid in reading order:

> Agatha Christie (P): N or M?, The Big Four, Dead Man's Folly, Five Little Pigs, The Secret of Chimneys, The Mystery of the Blue Train

> William Shakespeare (L): The Comedy of Errors, Julius Caesar, Twelfth Night, Much Ado About Nothing, Othello, Hamlet

> Charles Dickens (A): A Tale of Two Cities, Bleak House, Our Mutual Friend, Great Expectations, Hard Times

> John Le Carré (G): The Honourable Schoolboy, The Night Manager, A Perfect Spy, The Constant Gardner, A Most Wanted Man

> C.S. Lewis (I): The Horse and His Boy; The Silver Chair; The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe; The Last Battle; Prince Caspian

> Stephen King (A): Firestarter, It, Cell, Insomnia, Misery

> Terry Pratchett (R): Eric; Lords and Ladies; Guards! Guards!; Snuff; Making Money; Small Gods

But for the eighth,

> Enid Blyton,

I didn't know what to do until [fljx pointed it out](/a/122872): so go see and upvote that answer.

Comment: For the final set: rot13(Ybbx ng gur Snzbhf Svir frevrf, naq lbh pna svg va gur sbyybjvat gvgyrf ol gur ersreraprq nhgubef - Gbtrgure Ntnva, Eha Njnl, Gernfher Vfynaq, Gur Frn)

Comment: @fljx oh, nice find. I think you oughta post a separate answer post with that one.

Comment: Will do. Watch this space.

Comment: I think it might also be worth mentioning that rot13(gur svefg yrggref bs gur nhgubef' anzr va gurve nantenzzrq sbez fcryy bhg "FJVARFGL", n ersrerapr gb hfr gur "CVTCRA" pvcure.)

Comment: @Alaiko oh, cool, I hadn't seen that. Thanks

Comment: This is correct, well done :) Would you like to add fljx's contribution (with credit) for completeness?

Comment: @Stiv good point; done

Answer (score 8):

To fill in the missing final set in @msh210's answer:

> Every square references another author, and if we replace the author's name with the title of one of their works, we get the title a book in Enid Blyton's [Famous Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Famous_Five) series:
>
> John Banville - "The Sea" - "Five Go Down To The Sea"
>
> Robert Louis Stevenson - "Treasure Island" - "Five On A Treasure Island"
>
> Milly Johnson - "Together Again" - "Five Are Together Again"
>
> Harlen Coben - "Run Away" - "Five Run Away Together"
>
>  And that gives us the following:
>  [image]
>  Which is the final **Y**